# print parent directories full path of find output

Tags: shell, find, uniq, pwd

what I want to do is to find all files based on some search query and get parents parent directory (`../..`) full path.

For example `find . -name "__openerp__.py"` and then for each file execute something along the lines of `(cd ../..; pwd)`. Then pipe everything to `uniq`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming none of the file names contain newline characters:

```
find "$PWD" -name __openerp__.py  | awk -F/ -vOFS=/ 'NF-=2' | sort -u
```

Answer (score 3):

Putting aside that there would be issues with file names that contain newlines, there are a couple of efficiency improvements I can think of:

1. Pass the `$PWD` directly to find, instead of determining it for each sub-shell. This will make `find` include the full path in its output.
2. Cut parent directory names off with `rev` and `cut`.

So I would suggest the following to get a list of all directories containing the desired file:

```
find "$PWD" -name '__openerp__.py' |
rev                                | 
cut -d/ -f3-                       |
rev
```

Note that `find` does not order its output, so it should be sorted before uniq'ing it. As `sort` already supports squeezing identical elements (-u switch), the original question can then be answered with:

```
find "$PWD" -name '__openerp__.py' |
rev                                | 
cut -d/ -f3-                       |
rev                                |
sort -u
```

Comment: +1 Good point about `sort -u`. I initially thought that all the duplicate entries would be adjacent, but there isn't any reason for it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want the list of directories containing a subdirectory containing a file called `__openerp__.py`, without duplicates.

In zsh:

```
print -rl -- **/__openerp__.py(:h:h) | sort -u
```

or

```
a=(**/__openerp__.py(:h:h)); print -rl -- ${(u)a}
```

Comment: +1 for (:h:h) didn't knew this one in zsh globbing.

Answer (score -1):

```
find . -name "__openerp__.py" -exec sh -c '(cd "{}"/../../; pwd)' \; | uniq
```

Comment: Never include `{}` in the sh code.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas why?

Comment: Because it's interpreted as shell code, so if you have for instance a file called `$(rm -f "$HOME")`, it will have expensive consequences. Also it doesn't work at all in many `find` implementations. Use `sh -c 'cd -P "$1/../.." && pwd' sh {} \;` instead.